# Narrator not reading the description in higchart

Tags: highcharts, accessibility

I have some accessibility modules and I want to make a chart available to screen readers.  I started working with the basic description as follows (reference being https://www.highcharts.com/docs/accessibility/accessibility-module#describing-your-chart,):

Code -

```
  this.chart = new Highcharts.Chart('container',{
       
        accessibility: {
            description: 'This is the required chart'
        },
```

The narrator isn't reading the text. As per this example : https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/accessibility/accessible-bar I also tried specifying the description in series section, but I do not really understand why it is specified in this section.

Code -

```
 },
        series: [{
            name: chartSeries.success.name,
            data: 
                chartSeries.success.data,
                accessibility: {
                    description: 'This is the required chart'
                }
            },
```

Comment: Could you provide a demo of your issue?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ljXnzZi46zy6LpwaO4u6Z-6t7f1GR0xx/view?usp=sharing
This is the demo where it just say s"group" when graph in focus.
And as mentioned, the graph has : the above accessibility options specified

Comment: By demo I mean the reproduction of your code in the online editor. Are you able to recreate the issue? You can start from this template: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/accessibility/accessible-line

Comment: Even in the above mentioned template, the narrator isn't reading all the points. I also created a small demo : https://jsfiddle.net/kanika18/01zsadp8/22/ It should atleast read the chart description but that's not happening.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. What browser do you use? 2. Could you confirm that the Narratos is running in the Scan mode and you use the arrow key navigation? 3. What device do you use?

Comment: 1. Chrome 2. Using Ctrl+Win+Enter to run the browser narrator and using Tab keys to navigate 3. Windows machine

Comment: The problem is that you are using the tab keys to navigate. Tab only moves between interactive elements and the chart description/title etc is not interactive. This is intended behavior. Try to use arrow keys in Scan mode and it should work fine. More: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/accessibility/accessibility-module#basic-configuration

Comment: Thanks @SebastianWędzel. By using the arrow keys, the narrator read the chart description of the sample chart (https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/accessibility/accessible-line)
Can you please guide on what things need to be specified in code to make the narrator read the dynamic data of the chart?

Comment: It depends on what is your requirement, but I think that this doc should help you: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/accessibility/configure-the-accessibility-module

Comment: Thank you @SebastianWędzel.
I was able to implement accessibility. One more question, I have a chart with two series.
The narrator creates issue in reading the data in such scenario whereas with one series, it;s working. Any insights on this?

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue on some online editor?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pfsbyxwz/3/ There it is

Comment: @SebastianWędzel anything on this?

Comment: I tested your demo and works fine for me - the screen reader reads both series. Could you explain more precisely where the problem is?

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks for checking.
I am using Google chrome with inbuilt narrator using Ctrl+Win+Enter.

Comment: By using the down arrow key in combination with right-left arrows, I am unable to navigate properly. (Screen recording - https://cutt.ly/Tl24b7g )
Can you please guide me with what key combinations are you able to read it?